# Does our site scope include libraries?

Tags: discussion, scope

Libraries are treasuries for literary works. But are they on-topic at Lit.SE?

I think good questions about libraries can be asked:

- > What is the largest library in Europe?
- > How do libraries store rare or valuable books?
- > Where did [Collection X] from [Library Y] go when the library was closed down?

Does this fall within our site scope, or is this too distant from our core concept?

Comment: I like the second and third Qs, but the first one... meh.

Comment: @muru : It's the kind of question I probably wouldn't upvote, but: would I vote to close it as being off-topic?

Comment: IMO, questions about libraries *as they relate to the books* should be on topic; otherwise, not. That means your first one would be off topic, the other two on.

Comment: @Mithrandir : Just to clarify the point, what would you think of _Which library in Europe has the most books_ ?

Comment: That's hard. Probably off topic, as that's more about the building than the content, but... That's a hard one.

Comment: And, I'll state this plainly: the reason I think this is a question worth considering, is precisely because it's hard for me to see a clear line between "This question about libraries _is_ about literature, this one _isn't_." I suspect -- although I might certainly be wrong -- that we're going to need to take libraries or leave 'em pretty much as a whole.

Comment: The second and third questions deal with the effects of libraries on literature... But how does a library being the largest or having the most books matter to literature?

Comment: @muru : How does the storage procedure or location of books matter to literature?

Comment: @Standback the storage procedure and location matters in protection against loss of literature.

Comment: There is now a [Libraries and Information Science](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/108040/libraries-and-information-science?referrer=O-gl6OxAUH1AsNb2xoSuGA2) proposal, as shared by [Mithrandir](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1037?m=36664787#36664787).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think they should be **on-topic.**

Libraries are an important part of the literature community as they provide access to the public of the works we love. I'm sure many experts of literature have spent a good deal of time in libraries. I also do not see a current SE Site where they *would* be on-topic, so here is a good a place to attract new users with new questions that they may not been able to ask elsewhere. (As I typed that out, I realized there may be some overlap with Academia depending on what their scope is.)

To address your specific example questions:

1. On-topic, but would might be downvoted as a lack of research (Google bring up a one-box when you search).
2. On-topic, but has a slight possibility to be too broad. Although, I'm sure there are some accepted ways that could make a good answer.
3. On-topic, and I see no issues with it.

Comment: "I also do not see a current SE Site where they would be on-topic, so here is a good a place as any." That doesn't seem like a good argument for a scope discussion, but otherwise I agree with your answer.